# Change data type from string to date while skipping missing data

Tags: mongodb, date

The core collection (other collections in the DB refer back to this one) in my DB contains 3 fields with **date** information which at this point is formatted as strings like **MM/DD/YYYY**. Further, there are a range of documents for which this field contains missing data, i.e. **""**. I populated this collection by running the `mongoimport` command on a JSON file.

My goal is to convert these date-fields into actual `ISODate` data types, so as to allow filtering the collection by dates. Further, I want MongoDB to know that empty strings indicate missing values. I have read quite widely on this, leading me to try a bunch of things:

1. Trying a `forEach` statement - This worked, but only for the very first document.

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(element){
   element.startDate = ISODate(element.startDate);
   db.collection.save(element);
})
```

2. Using kind of a for-loop: this worked well, but stopped once it encountered a missing value (so it transformed about 11 values):

```
db.collection.update(
     {
        "startDate":{
           "$type":"string"
        }
     },
     [
        {
           "$set":{
              "startDate":{
                 "$dateFromString":{
                    "dateString":"$startDate",
                    "format":"%m/%d/%Y"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  )
```

So, both of these approaches kind of worked - but I don't know how to apply them to the entire collection. Further, I'd be interested in performing this task in the most efficient way possible. However, I only want to do this once - data that will be added in the future should hopefully be correctly formatted at the import stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {
        "$and": [
            { "startDate": { "$type": "string" } },
            { "startDate": { "$ne": "" } }
        ]
    },
    [
       {
        "$set": {
            "startDate": {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": "$startDate",
                    "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
)
```

Filtering out empty string than doing the transformation will ignore documents that have empty string in date field.

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks so much for your reply. This query definitely makes sense to me. However, it isn't working unfortunately... I'm getting this error message: 

`writeError" : {
  "code" : 52,
  "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromString' in 'startDate.$dateFromString' is not valid for storage."
 }`

Comment: so actually I was able to fix it. You need to wrap the update parameters in `[]`. I'll edit this in your answer and accept it. Many thanks!